# Using an ajaxRequest.open to send a variable to php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a script which uses ajaxRequest.open to call a php script. I'm wondering how I could send a variable to the php file. More specifically, I've got a form text field I'd like to be able to send to the php file.

The ajaxRequest is working fine, I just need to know how I'd send a variable and how php could read it.

Here is the (very abbreviated) script which is calling my php file...

```
}
  ajaxRequest.open("GET", "../../ajaxphp.php", true);
  ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/send-post-data-using-xmlhttprequest

Answer (score 1):

Append it as a querystring to the request:

```
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "../../ajaxphp.php?myvar=thevalue", true);
```

And then in your PHP

```
$myvar = $_GET['myvar'];
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to obtain the value of variable witch you are going to send to *.php
You can do it by this ways:

```
var value = document.getElementById("someID").value;
```

or jQuery way:

```
var value = $("#someID").val();
```

Then, you need to put the variable to your ajax request:

```
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "../../ajaxphp.php?variable="+value, true);
//The last argument in this line (witch is set a "true") want to say, that is a  asynchronous request 
ajaxRequest.send(null);
//null want to say, that you not sending any parameter, really is automatically sent in the first line of code
```

Then, when you pick up the value of the variable in the code *. php, can do the next:

```
<?php
$myVariable = $_GET["variable"];
echo $myVariable;
?>
```

Or like this:

```
<?
$myVariable = $_REQUEST["variable"];
echo $$myVariable;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send data by simply appending parameters to the URL like

```
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "../../ajaxphp.php?foo=bar", true);
```

To get a value from an input field using javascript, you may do the following

```
var foo = document.getElementById('foo').value;
```

To get the value from the URL using PHP

```
$foo = $_GET['foo'];
```

Full example

```
<input id="foo" name="foo" value="bar">

<script>

    var foo = document.getElementById('foo').value;
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "../../ajaxphp.php?foo="+foo, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null);

</script>
```

PHP file

```
<?php

    $foo = $_GET['foo'];
    echo $foo;

?>
```